# multiple threads print value together

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

I'm trying to understand why I got this answer while I run this code in thread.
I don't understand why i don't get different i value each time.
[image]

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *printHello(void *threadid)
{
    int tid = *(int*)threadid;  

    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%d!\n", tid);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", i,);

        rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printHello, &i);

        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

do all the thread wait until they finish to create them and then they go to printHello function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new thread, there is no fixed order of thread execution. The main thread and the newly created thread(s) will simply run concurrently to each other.

The problem with respect to your `i` variable is that you're passing in the *address* of `i` to the `pthread_create` function. Since this variable gets updated upon subsequent loop iterations, its value will change when you access it via its address (from within the `printHello` callback function). In your output, we can see that the loop in the `main` function has finished before any of the spawned threads output anything, since `i` has reached the `NUM_THREADS` limit already.

If you want things to be deterministic, then create a new variable to hold the thread IDs, and pass in the address location for that thread instead:

```
int threadIds[NUM_THREADS];
int rc;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
{
    threadIds[i] = i;
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printHello, threadIds + i);
}
```

Also, block on the main thread until all spawned threads have finished executing, and don't invoke `pthread_exit` in the `main` function. It is not running inside of a pthread, and so it does not need exiting.